# Is there a term for generally not wanting to be associated with established groups?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I usually stay away from considering myself to belong to groups<sup>1</sup> because I don't have control over them and their reputation derived either from actions committed in the past, present or future by those who were, are or will consider themselves or be considered by others as members of such aforementioned groups, or from different definitions of what the groups are about, causing as a result different interpretations and assumptions with prejudice.

That way, from my view, most stereotypes and presumptions can be avoided even if I do have some similarities that would make someone associate me with a particular group.

Is there a term that resembles that of what I just explained?

---

<sup>1</sup> Examples of what I mean by groups from the top of my head (list not exhaustive and possibly slightly incorrect):

- Religion: buddhism, christianism, including (non-religions terms/philosofies) atheism, theism, nihilism, and so on.
- Political parties/systems like anarchy, democracy, dictatorship, monarchy, those kinds of views and whatnot.
- Particular subjects / others: gamer, virgin, weeaboo, introvert, extrovert.
- Gender (online).
- Etc...

Comment: So you would like a name that describes a categorization that you can belong to that says you don’t want to associate yourself with any categorization??

Comment: @Jim Sort of a non-correlation to groups in general. In a way apathetic/non-participative/detached/disassociated from norms, I guess. It's not that I have something against everything, it's that I want to make clear that I'm me and not what any associations say I am.

Comment: Right, but whatever we come up with it will be you and all the others like you that will fit that group.

Comment: @Jim It does contradict itself to be "part of a group that isn't part of groups". What I'm looking for is not a group but a neutral term/word free from the usual prejudices that simply means kind of what I explained.

Comment: @Jim For example, apathetic is close to being that term but it can still be criticized negatively upon by societies with some significant reasoning power saying someone apathetic "lacks interest", "is bland/unenthusiastic" or "is unconcerned/unresponsive".

Comment: "Apathetic" is rather different. It means you can't be bothered to participate in a group, but I take the question to mean actively avoiding established groups. For example you play golf, but deliberately avoid the clubhouse and hole 19, and any invitations. Perhaps you are a **loner** or a **nonconformist**.

Comment: 'I don't want to be any part of a group that will accept members.' (after Marx)

Comment: @KannE Interesting lyrics. I don't think the meaning would be understood in most situations but thanks for sharing.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're not too far-fetched. I don't exactly mind if for example a close friend says for example that I'm atheist and talk about it, its more about the avoiding people that don't know me well enough that might be sometimes more arrogant or joke too much or something which can get annoying even if unintentionally or if it's just how they are.

Comment: @PhilSweet That was actually already mentioned in [another comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/523467/is-there-a-term-for-generally-not-wanting-to-be-associated-with-established-grou?noredirect=1#comment1274532_523467). I should just approach these type of issues differently.

Answer (score 1):

The most generic term available for this is ***undefined*** or ***not defined,*** depending on which flows better in speech.

Because a definition for ***undefined*** gives you something along the lines of *not defined*, here is the definition for **define.** I'll be going with the sense in #3 on [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/define):

> **define**
>   *verb*
>
> 3. Characterize; Distinguish
>      *you define yourself by the choices you make*

This tells us that someone who is **undefined** is not characterized or distinguished. Forms of distinguishing someone by association are, then, caught by this phrase.

> Are you a Christian?
>   No, I am not. As a matter of fact, I don't belong to any group, religious or social. I am ***undefined*** by those things.

Comment: That's an interesting choice. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

A word which perhaps fits is ***unclubbable*** - but unfortunately it does carry a negative sense.

Its OED entry reads as follows:

> Not clubbable; (of a person) not suitable for membership of a club
>   owing to lack of sociability or desire to conform; (of a
>   characteristic) that does not inspire friendly relations; unsociable.
>
> ?1764   F. Burney Early Jrnls. & Lett. (1994) III. 76   Sir John was a
>   most unclubable man!
>
> 1859   G. A. Sala Twice round Clock (1861) 215   Moreover, they are a
>   people who drink standing,..a most unclubable characteristic.
>
> 1867   E. Yates Forlorn Hope I. x. 222   Kilsyth is not popular at
>   Barnes's, being decidedly an unclubbable man.
>
> 1960   Proc. Royal Music Assoc. 86th Sess. 11   As a musician he was
>   certainly outstanding but he seems to have been a rather undisciplined
>   and unclubbable character.
>
> 2016   Daily Mail (Nexis) 7 July   She is stubborn, unclubbable,
>   unimpeachable, not frightened by the will of others, quietly
>   determined.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Though I think most people including me would have to search the meaning of it and still not get it too well or would have to ask which in that case I would have just explained in the first place. ^^'

Comment: @user7393973 Are you saying you would not use it because no one would understand what it meant?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you are looking for **unbelonging** or **unbelongingness**.

It is the opposite of *belongingness* defined as:

> The state or feeling of belonging to a particular group. 
>   - [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/belongingness).

Here is a relevant excerpt from the book *Interrogating Belonging for Young People in Schools* (edited by Christine Halse - 2018):

> Unbelonging can be imposed, for example when a government rejects a refugee's application for asylum, a religion ostracises a member of its flock, or a peer group shuns one of its members. **Unbelonging can also be an act of individual or group agency, a conscious choice or deliberate resistance to the idea, position or experience of belonging.** This would be the case, for example, when a young person deliberately rejects the beliefs and practices of racist, misogynist or homophobic group or consciously defies the rules and governmentality that are a condition for belonging in a school community (see Hayes and Skattebol 2015).

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>